# Why does my Nextjs route parameter sometimes resolve to "null" when it is explicity defined

Tags: next.js, getserversideprops

I noticed that when I go to the route "`/stream/[provider]/[streamerId]`" in my browser the page loads successfully, but I can also see the page also prints to console a 404 stating that the url is "`/stream/YouTube/null`", even though I passed in the url "`/stream/YouTube/ucyazpsxowcye_ffhs-jurcw`" for example. I would like for the undesired URL to never show, since it is simply not the case of the value `[streamerId]` not being provided.

The directory of the page that is rendering this page is `/stream/[provider]/[streamerId]/index.tsx` by the way.

In my `getServerSideProps` function, I added a null check for `streamerId` so that it returns a notFound error before it performs any additional logic, but it turns out that null is being passed as a string, so the following conditional was needed:

```js
if (!streamerId || streamerId === "null") {
  return {
    notFound: true,
  };
}
```

I checked in our server/index.js file too and wrote the following code to log the URL, and noticed that pathName sometimes contains the correct route "`/stream/YouTube/ucyazpsxowcye_ffhs-jurcw`", and other times it will print "`/stream/YouTube/null`":

```js
app.get(
  "*",
  syncMuid,
  syncLocaleAndRoute,
  addSecurityHeaders,
  cacheMiddleware,
  (req, res) => {
    const { path: pathName, query } = req;
    console.log("pathname--------------", pathName);
    console.log("query-----------------", query);

    return nextHandler(req, res);
  }
);
```

Comment: I'd like to also mention that I checked inside all of those handlers inside the `app.get` function call and they are also producing the same behavior where somtimes it passes in the correct URL, and other times it passes in streamerId = null

Comment: I'm also getting "null" passed in sometimes. Not sure why.